# The fixed point in Brouwer's Theorem need not be unique.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

What does it mean for a fixed point to be unique?  I'm thinking that it means that you can have multiple values of a fixed point.

But, a fixed point is one where $f(x) = x$.  So to have repeated fixed points means that $f(x) = x$ and $f(y) = x$.

But then $y$ isn't a fixed point.

Just so that I have the definition correct, when finding an example of a function with non-unique fixed points, am I looking for a function who has more than one fixed point?

Any clarification would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Right, a unique fixed point means only one point is... fixed.

Comment: It means the fixed point has a pink reverse mohawk. Its special.

Answer (score 2):

Unique in this context means that there is only one fixed point. Brower's Theorem does not guarantee that there is only one fixed point, because this is false in general. For example, consider $f:[0,1]\to[0,1],x\mapsto x$. Then $f$ has infinitely many fixed points (each point in $[0,1]$).

Compare this to the fixed point theorem of Banach. There you get a unique (i.e. only one) fixed point!

Answer (score 1):

Think of the function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ given by $f(x)=x$. How many fixed points does it have?